# Allow anonymous access to specific URL in web.config

Tags: php, angularjs, iis, web-config, iis-7.5

This site is running PHP on IIS 7.5, and access to the site is restricted to an Active Directory group via the web.config, as follows:

```
<security>
    <authorization>
        <remove users="*" roles="" verbs="" />
        <add accessType="Allow" roles="DOMAIN\AD-GROUP" />
    </authorization>
 </security>
```

The only URL rewriting being done is to send most URLs to `index.php`, and CodeIgniter handles routing after that.

There's a specific URL pattern that needs to be exposed to users not in that specific Active Directory group, however. It's not a file, which I believe the `<location>` tag is used for; it needs to be based on the URL.

Additional context: this is for a URL pattern in a single page/AngularJS application. An example: in a project management application, users of the app can create tasks, upload files, post notes (e.g., http://domain/#/project/1234/tasks). All of those users are in the `AD-GROUP` group. For each project, there's a cover page of sorts for the project that can be given out to non-users within the organization (http://domain/#/project/1234/public). They won't be in that specific AD group, but they need to view that page.

Is this possible to do in the web.config, given that it's based on the hash in the URL? If not, what's an alternate way to restrict based on an AD group if not the web.config?

Answer (score 1):

I think that `<location>` is still the way to go. According to the documentation at https://www.iis.net/learn/get-started/planning-your-iis-architecture/deep-dive-into-iis-configuration-with-iis-7-and-iis-8 path might be not just local files

> The main attribute on location tags is "path". The values can be:
>
> ...
>
> - "sitename/application/vdir": A specific virtual directory of a specific application of a specific site.

Comment: I haven't been able to get this to work. Any attempt to put a regex in as a path results in an error about invalid characters.

Comment: @MelissaAvery-Weir, yes this is not designed to work with path matched by RegExp. If you can't put a fixed prefix in your URLs, I think the next simplest solution is to install [URL Rewrite module](https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite) and use it to map all your URLS to a prefix-physical folder and configure `location` for that folder.

Comment: All incoming URLs are being mapped to an `index.php` file already for CodeIgniter to drive routing. Further research is suggesting this is even less possible than I'd hoped: the URL that needs the security exception is in the hash portion of the URL (for AngularJS). I don't even think hashes make it to the server; you can't do URL rewriting on them.

Comment: So you mean you mean you want `example.com/index.php#secure` to be restricted but `example.com/index.php#public` to be allowed for everyone? I don't think this is possible but I'm not sure why you have such a strange design. When a user opens one of those two pages, how the server is expected to distinguish which one to serve? And if distinction is done only on the client side, you probably still can make your data-requests (AJAX) to different URLs some of which will be public and some require authorization.

Comment: I updated the question to provide more details. It's an entire SPA/AngularJS app, so the design isn't too strange. :-) Thanks for helping me work through this! It's a weird problem.

Comment: @MelissaAvery-Weir, I think you didn't answered my last set of questions: what do you expect behavior to be and how you imagine it to work inside? If you actually use the same URL as in SPA, then all the data served before your first JS is exectuted (HTML, JS, CSS) must be the same for public and secure URLs. The first place capable to distinct them is inside your JS on the client. As I said you can (and I believe should) additionally protect your data request and here web.config might help you, but still you must handle unauthorized access errors to them in the client-side JS.

Comment: I'd originally expected to be able to give an entire URL pattern (including the hash) to the server to differentiate, but you're absolutely right: all the static assets and all AJAX requests would suffer the same restrictions. I'll need a way to check authorization on the client-side instead, as you said.

Comment: Since this answer/discussion helped clarify that what I originally wanted wasn't possible and that my thinking was erroneous, I'm happy to give you the bounty!

Comment: @MelissaAvery-Weir I'd still like to re-iterate, that I think that proper security **must** involve server-side access protection, not only client-side hiding of UI. Otherwise anyone how can read JS will be able to read and modify your data. I am not aware of how CodeIgniter works and I am not even a PHP developer, but still I can't imagine why you can't have at least two entry points "public.php" and "authorized.php" both of which internally delegate (include?) to the same "index.php" but have different access restrictions in the web.config. Alternatively, you may validate access in the code.

Comment: Agreed. They would have different access restrictions in the web.config and in the server-side code to ensure that "public.php" isn't used to make random AJAX requests; only what's needed for the page in question. Do you want to update your answer to include a synopsis of this? If so (or I can do it), I'll mark it as the answer.